# Sort Users by Score with respect to a Tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting, top-users, tag-score

Is there a way to sort users under a certain tag?  For example, if I want to see all users who have answered questions tagged `iphone` in order of their `iphone`-specific score, how would I do it?

Comment: You'd probably have to use the Data Explorer. This information isn't really useful that they'd allow you to browse *all* users who have answered in a tag. You can see the [top users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/iphone/topusers) though.

Comment: Just look for me :) haha, just kidding

Answer (score 6):

1. Click on the name of a tag.
2. Go to the info tab
3. You will see a list of top answerers for this tag.